# css z index/overflow results are coming in background

Tags: css

I have this page where in search box results are not being shown properly.

http://www.way2enjoy.com/touch/default-1.php

I changed the overflow to visible/hidden/overflow and all other option for search results which is being shown in display div. I tried to change the div css of below box as well to show the results but it is being shown in background.
If I change the below div x to hidden then the bottom menu will shift to left/right whatever we set so I dont want that to shifted. Just I'm looking for results to be dispalyed properly.
I think z index should work so I have set z index to 1000 and even set it as important then  also search results are being displayed in background. Any advise will be useful to me.

Comment: have you tried position: absolute ?

Comment: Your results have a transparent background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `position:absolute` to #display

This will bring it forward and also prevent it from pushing the content beneath to the right.

Comment: thx but i am very disappointed .i missed to think this option.:( i was knowing that something very very common thing i am missing but i could not strike